# PHP Errors Echo database rows

Tags: php, html, css, sql, phpmyadmin

```
    <?php
mysql_connect('localhost','example','example');

$result = mysql_query("blakesdatabase` LIMIT 0, 30 "); 
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result); 

// Display the results 
echo $num_rows; 

?>
```

I am trying to store some text in a database I have set up. I am trying to get the PHP to reconise my new database I have set up and display the rows of text I put in.

For some reason I am getting some kind of PHP error saying that `mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in`

I have no idea what this means. Sorry, I am new to PHP. Basically what I am trying to do is store text in a database and display the results on my page.

Does anyone have any php examples on how to echo out rows in a SQL database?

Thank you

Comment: You're not selecting anything, plus not selecting a DB. Do find a good MySQL tutorial.

Comment: What kind of query is it? where did you learn how to write sql query like that?

Comment: *sidenote:* stop using deprecated `mysql_*` functions. use [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead.

Comment: In the case of an UPDATE or INSERT query, the function returns a boolean to indicate success or failure -- not a resource. Further, you'd use `mysql_affected_rows()`, not `mysql_num_rows()`, to get the "result" of this type of operation. I'd suggest taking a closer look at PHP.net's documentation for `mysql_query`.

Comment: Select item FROM table - simplest query

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to learn how to write SQL as there are a lot of things you should know before embarking on creating an application that uses a database.

After that, you'll want to abandon the `mysql_*` functions entirely. There are better ways to query a MySQL database in PHP. I recommend PDO. You'll want a tutorial on using PDO in PHP for MySQL. This one seems to cover the basics and covers what you'll need to do. It also explains why you shouldn't use the `mysql_*` functions (essentially, the `mysql_` extensions are deprecated for various reasons, including having to escape your own queries which leaves a lot more room for errors that could result in SQL injection holes).

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php-database-access-are-you-doing-it-correctly--net-25338

Basically, with PDO, you'll create a connection, run your query, and loop through your results. It's not a whole lot different from the `mysql_` functions for what you're trying to do, but it's a LOT safer.

Comment: Before he learns PDO / MySQLi, OP must learn how to write proper SQL statement first.

Answer (score 0):

**try this:**

```
<?php
mysql_connect("hostname","db_username","db_password");
mysql_select_db("dbname");
$check_user = "select * from table where username='$username' AND password='$password'";

$run = mysql_query($check_user);


$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($run); 

// Display the results 
echo $num_rows; 

?>
```